# Click event to delete and refresh div content

Tags: onclick, refresh

As a noob to the JS universe, I had a question pertaining to a click event for a basic Quote Generator program. The idea is that upon clicking the '.generate' button, the content that appears within the 'taskEl' paragraph is deleted and refreshed with the next randomly generated quote. Thank you for any help with this.

```
<body>
    <div class="card">
        <button type ="button" class="generate">Generate Quote</button>
    </div>

<script>
    
    const quote = document.querySelector('.generate');
    const card = document.querySelector('.card');

    const myQuotes = ['It was the best of times, it was the worst of times', 'To the victor belong the spoils', 'Float like a butterfly, sting like a bee', 'No man is an island'];

    const people = ['Charles Dickens', 'William Marcy', 'Muhammad Ali', 'John Donne'];

    quote.addEventListener('click', getQuote);
  
    function getQuote() {

        const taskEl = document.createElement('p');
        const taskEl2 = document.createElement('p');
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * myQuotes.length);
        
        taskEl.className = 'outputBox';
        taskEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myQuotes[random]));
        card.appendChild(taskEl);
        
        taskEl2.className = 'sourceBox';
        taskEl2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(people[random]));
        card.appendChild(taskEl2);
        
    };
    getQuote();
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to place `click` attribute inside html element, like this:

```
<button type ="button" class="generate" onclick="getQuote()">Generate Quote</button>
```

To substitude the contents of a paragraph use `innerText`.

```
taskEl.innerText = 'some random quote';
```